# How to capture structured xUnit test output in Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab-ci, xunit

I am running automated tests on a .NET Core codebase on Gitlab CI. The only output from these tests is the console which contains a lot of garbage and makes it difficult to see exactly which tests failed.

Is there a way to get structured test output from xUnit in such a way that Gitlab can process the file and display results for specific tests much in the way it can with [JUnit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html)?

Answer (score 9):

First, add the [JUnitTestLogger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JUnitTestLogger/) nuget package to your test project:

`dotnet add package JUnitTestLogger`

Next, modify your test command:

`dotnet test --logger "junit;LogFileName=MyProject.xml"`

Finally, modify your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to specify the output path:

```
test:
  ...
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: ./MyProject.xml
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's change or not, but I had to use "juni;LogFilePath=MyProject.xml" - LogFilePATH not LogFileNAME.

Comment: The behavior of `LogFileName` changed in 2019 and [seems](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/1951) to do something different now. Use `LogFilePath` instead.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add the `JUnitTestLogger` NuGet package
2. Use test command like: `dotnet test --logger "junit;LogFilePath={path_to_XML_file}"`
3. Modify `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (look at my example). You have to use the parameters: `when`, `paths`, `reports`

```
... 
stages: 
  ...
  - tests 

variables:   
 LOGFILEPATH: /builds/myname/myrepository.api.tests/JUnitTestLogFile.xml ...

test_job:
    stage: tests
    script:
    - dotnet test --logger "junit;LogFilePath="$LOGFILEPATH
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
        - $LOGFILEPATH
        reports:
            junit: $LOGFILEPATH
```

Comment: This will not work if the path is not absolute, you would need to change to `LogFilePath=../"$LOGFILEPATH` to place the .xml file outside the project file, so you can correctly collect it. Can you modify your comment to warn people of this? A wasted some time figuring it out...