# Producing a xUnit test output similar to Junit output on gitlab CI

Tags: junit, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, xunit

We have `.NET Core 3` codebase and the unit and integration tests are ran on the `Gitlab CI`.
Problem is, when one or more unit/int. tests fail, nothing specific is shown, you have to look at the entire pipeline dump and search to see for individual failed tests.

Looking at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html, Junit report is exactly solving this issue.

Consulting with the [How to capture structured xUnit test output in Gitlab CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574782/how-to-capture-structured-xunit-test-output-in-gitlab-ci), I still wasn't able to find a proper solution.
Main problem is, there are multiple test projects that are executed with the `dotnet test` command:

current snapshot of gitlab.yaml file:

```
  artifacts: 
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: ./Test.xml   
  script:
    - for proj in $(dotnet sln MySolution.sln list | grep 'Test.csproj$'); do dotnet test --logger "junit;LogFilePath=Test.xml" $proj; done
```

Now the problematic is the script part, where we iterate through all the test assemblies and do the dotnet test for each project.

Is there a way to somehow produce a single junit xml log file out of each project and feed it to junit test report in the

```
 reports:
  junit: ./Test.xml
```

line?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to combine the reports. The `artifacts:reports:junit` key accepts multiple values, including glob patterns.

```
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - "test.xml"
        - "./tests/*.xml"
```

So, one solution would be to have all your XML output files in a particular directory and use a glob pattern in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that matches the many files.

If you really want to merge the xUnit XML files isntead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58092705/5747944)